# How to highlight portions of the Nav?

Tags: css, frontend, css-grid

I'm working on coding my own portfolio for my UX/UI program.
I have my nav styled with the following CSS:

```
.nav-links {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-start: span;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: eurostile, sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  justify-items: center;
  background-color: #7510f7;
  margin-right: -10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.nav-item a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: lighter;
}
```

Each nav link is contained within one column of the grid.

I'm trying to figure out how I can get a specific column of the grid to change background color in order to indicate which page the user is on. Is this possible in CSS? Or is there another way for me to indicate which page the user is on?

Edit: Here is the HTML for the Nav:

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="contextual_inquiry.html">Contextual Inquiry</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="interaction_Design.html">Interaction Design</a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="skills.html">Skills</a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="about.html">About</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Edit: I published the website for people to better visualize it: https://gnenadov.github.io/portfolio/home

Comment: can you add a snippet or at least the html

Comment: @AkhilAravind Added the HTML for the Nav in the original post as an edit

Comment: From the above markup, its clear that you are using html, so for each html you will add the `nav` code block. Just create a class `active` and add that to the `nav li` with the desired style

Comment: @AkhilAravind so stying with the active class is working, however I'm running into some issues. Setting the background-color is only changing the text itself basically into a block of that color. So I tried setting the font-weight to "bold" in the .active class, and it does not appear to be working.

Comment: you may have added font-weight in some other markups, just add `!important`, that is `font-weight:bold !important;` to the active class, it should work

Comment: @AkhilAravind hm, still not working, even with the !important added. Other style tags such as background-color are working, so I have not selected it wrong. Could there be something preventing the weight:bold !important from working? I set the weight in the style for the nav items (shown up above)

Comment: the nav context is already in bold, so why are you trying to add bold to it ?

Comment: @AhkilAravind I’m confused. I set it to “lighter” with font-weight in the .nav-item a, so I should be able to change it to font-weight: bold in the .active right? Terribly sorry for my ignorance, only been writing CSS for a month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may add a class may be `active` to the li pragmatically as you must know the active page and then use this class to style whatever you want

Comment: So make a style for .active and then add the class "active" to the nav li on the correct page essentially?